# nvidia-prime switching to intel stopped working

Tags: nvidia, 14.04, nvidia-prime

I can no longer switch between my intel and nvidia cards, it used to work and my default card was intel now for some reason its nvidia and i can no longer switch and the PRIME profile option has disappeared from nvidia-settings. When launching nvidia-settings from terminal i get:

```
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
Failed to open VDPAU backend libvdpau_nvidia.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
** Message: PRIME: No offloading required. Abort
** Message: PRIME: is it supported? no
```

I don't really know when it stopped working but some time in the last 3 days i think.
Any one knows what has happend?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same portable. This is what I did:

Steps

```
Install Nouveau driver through "Software & updates"
```

Remove bumblebee or other installed nvidia drivers:

```
sudo apt-get purge bumblebee*
sudo apt-get purge nvidia-*
```

An then reboot

Install `nvidia 331-updates` driver through "Software & updates" (should also install nvidia-settings and nvidia-prime)

Then reboot